# SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR - laravel

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, laravel-8, rest

Below given is an API to upload files.
it shows error -

`SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"Userid\" of relation \"files\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (7, null, Distance Learning Promo.mp4, null, null, null, 2021-07-07 13:38:07, 2021-07-07 13:38:07). (SQL: insert into \"files\" (\"FileName\", \"updated_at\", \"created_at\") values (Distance Learning Promo.mp4, 2021-07-07 13:38:07, 2021-07-07 13:38:07) returning \"id\")` .

And Postman shows the status `500 internal status error`.

I don't think my `Userid` column here is null . Pls help me with some suggestions

**Controller**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Uploads;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $file=$request->file('file_name');
        $fileName=$file->getClientOriginalName();

        $folder = uniqid().'-'.now()->timestamp;
        $file->storeAs('public/other-document/'.$folder, $fileName);
       
       $filePath = $folder.'/'.$fileName;
       $dataToInsert = array();
       $dataToInsert['FileName'] = $fileName;
       $dataToInsert['FilePath'] = $filePath;
       if($request->has('uploadType'))
       {
           $dataToInsert['FileType'] = $request->uploadType;
       }
       $dataToInsert['uploadedBy'] = Auth::user()->id;
       $dataToInsert['Userid'] = $request->bearerToken();
       Uploads::create($dataToInsert); 
    }

}
```

**Migration file**

```
Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('Userid');
            $table->string('FileName');
            $table->string('FilePath');
            $table->string('FileType');
            $table->integer('uploadedBy');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: please check the `$dataToInsert['Userid'] = $request->bearerToken();` holds any value

Comment: @JEJ it holds value. even if `Userid` column is inserted a dummy value like this also-  `$dataToInsert['Userid'] =1` ,it shows the same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $dataToInsert['Userid'] = $request->bearerToken(); // error is here

if(!$dataToInsert['Userid']){
 return "Null value in userID";
}
```

Check the  `$dataToInsert['Userid']` holds any value.

Also make Sure that Your are Passing bearerToken  in header

Comment: it holds value. even if Userid column is inserted a dummy value like this also- $dataToInsert['Userid'] =1 ,it shows the same error.

Comment: @MG check Your Fillables in Model